# C# Passing value of a list element to update local variable

Tags: c#, .net, variables

I have a few local variables and I want to divide them all divide them all by the same number.

```
decimal a = 0;
decimal b = 0;
decimal c = 0; 
...
decimal n = 0;
decimal divisor = 0;

<perform calculations to give all variables meaningful values>

divide each decimal (a - n) by divisor then assign value
```

Beside dividing and assigning every variable with:

```
a = a / divisor;
b = b / divisor;
and so on...
```

Is there a faster way? I'm thinking something along the lines of putting them all in a collection and iterating over it...

I don't need the values in a list, I need the variables to contain them. I was thinking of something along the lines using a list of pointers, iterating over it and setting the values that way.

Comment: That wouldn't be *faster*. If you care about *faster*, then write a performance specification, write performance tests, determine whether you've met your spec. If not, get out a profiler, find the slowest thing, fix it.  Repeat until you're done.

Comment: That was a misuse of the word "faster". I meant less tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Be aware that this isn't the same as the first code though - it makes the list variable refer to a new list containing the divided numbers; if anything else has a reference to the original list, it won't see any changes." - J Skeet

Per the question - "I don't need the values in a list, I need the variables to contain them. I was thinking of something along the lines using a list of pointers, iterating over it and setting the values that way."

**This is not possible** and as Mr. Copsey pointed out - "You're better off working with the list of values, as Jon suggested. Trying to make a list of pointers to the original values, iterate over them, etc, will be more work than just setting them directly (plus much less maintainable)."

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely - use an array (`decimal[]`) or a `List<decimal>` then:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    list[i] /= divisor;
}
```

Alternatively, you could go for a more functional approach, which LINQ makes particularly easy:

```
IEnumerable<decimal> divided = list.Select(x => x / divisor);
```

You can build a new array or list from that `IEnumerable<decimal>` using the `ToArray` or `ToList` methods respectively. For example, you *could* write:

```
list = list.Select(x => x / divisor).ToList();
```

Be aware that this isn't the same as the first code though - it makes the `list` variable refer to a *new* list containing the divided numbers; if anything else has a reference to the original list, it won't see any changes.

Comment: I would like to iterate over a list of say pointers to the values but I need the values to be stored in the local variables at the end code sample.

Comment: You're better off working with the list of values, as Jon suggested.  Trying to make a list of pointers to the original values, iterate over them, etc, will be more work than just setting them directly (plus much less maintainable).

Answer (score 1):

If you have them in a collection, you can do something like that:

```
var myCollection = // setup the collection;

var newCollection = from i in myCollection
                    select i / divisor;
```

That will give you a new collection with all of the original elements divided by your "divisor" variable.

Comment: Yes but that doesn't update the variables. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: You should use Jon Skeet's first approach, then.  It will work correctly for iterating over the original list.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = new List<decimal>(14) {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n}
                   .ForEach(x => x /= divisor};
```

Of course, this won't actually adjust the variables a, b, c ... n.

Comment: "Of course, this won't actually adjust the variables a, b, c ... n." That is the problem, I need the variables updated.